# Why solving $Ax = b$ is equivalent to minimize $\frac{1}{2}x^TAx - b^Tx$ over x

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, numerical-linear-algebra

I cannot understand this equality: I found it in many webpages but no one explain why they lead to the same result. I understood that it is something about the gradient of $\frac{1}{2}x^TAx - b^Tx$, that is $Ax = b$, but I didn't understand in addition how do we know that the gradient is this one and which is the role of the gradient in this problem. Can someone explain with a mathematical proof or description how starting from $\frac{1}{2}x^TAx - b^Tx$ we can say that it is equivalent to $Ax = b$?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm searching for a mathematical proof or explanation that tells why they're equivalent, starting from $\frac{1}{2}x^TAx-b^T$

Comment: We should assume that $A$ is symmetric positive definite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write the function $f(x) = \frac 12 x^TAx-b^Tx$ as follows:
$$f(x) = \frac 12 \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}x_ix_j - \sum_{k=1}^n b_kx_k$$
which leads to
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_l}f = \frac 12 \bigg ( \sum_{j=1}^n a_{lj}x_j + \sum_{i=1}^n a_{il}x_i \bigg ) - b_l$$
and therefore the gradient is
$$\nabla f= \frac 12 (Ax + A^Tx) - b$$
So if $A=A^T$ (so $A$ is symmetric), we have $\nabla f = Ax-b$ and at any minimum of $f$ we know that $\nabla f=0$ has to be true. So when $Ax=b$, we obtain $\nabla f=0$. We have to find an argument why this is truly a minimum and why it couldn't be a maximum. For that we can look at the second derivatives

$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_mx_l} f = \frac 12 (a_{lm} + a_{ml})$$
which leads to $H_f = \frac 12 (A+A^T)$. If $A$ is symmetric, this means $H_f=A$. Now we know that we have a minimum if the Hessian $H_f$ is positive definite.

In conclusion, we have ONLY if $A$ is symmetric and positive definite, that finding a minimum of $f(x) = \frac 12 x^TAx-b^Tx$ is equivalent to solving $Ax=b$, because in that case the Hessian is $H_f=A$, so only a minimum can be achieved and the gradient $\nabla f$ vanishes iff $Ax=b$.

Comment: @ElenaFranchini It's not $A$ that is positive definite, it is the Hessian $H_f$. The fact that we have a minimum when it is positive definite is a calculus fact (which generalizes the fact that we know we have a minimum of a function $f$ of one variable when $f''(x) > 0$).

Comment: Yes I read it again and I understood, thank you very much, it is a very good explanation

Answer (score 2):

Here's a proof that doesn't use calculus. I'll assume $A \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ is symmetric positive definite. And I'll make use of the  "$A$-norm" $\| \cdot \|_A$ on $\mathbb R^n$ defined by $\| y \|_A = \sqrt{y^T A y}$.

Suppose that $x^*$ is the unique solution to $Ax = b$. Then
\begin{align}
\|x - x^*\|_A^2 &= (x - x^*)^T A (x - x^*) \\
&= x^T A x - 2x^T A x^* + {x^*}^T A x^* \\
&= x^T A x - 2x^T b + \underbrace{{x^*}^T A x^*}_{\substack{\text{Does not}\\ \text{depend on $x$}}}.
\end{align}
The quantity $\| x - x^* \|_A^2$ is minimized when $x = x^*$, of course. So we can see that the function
$$
f(x) = x^T Ax - 2 x^T b
$$ is also minimized when $x = x^*$.

---

Alternatively, if we want to use calculus, here's a way to compute the gradient of the function
$f(x) = x^T A x - 2 x^T b$. First let's discover a product rule for the derivative of the function
$$
F(x) = \langle g(x), h(x) \rangle
$$
where $g: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ and $h: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ are differentiable functions. Notice that
\begin{align}
F(x + \Delta x) &= \langle g(x + \Delta x, h(x + \Delta x) \rangle \\
&\approx \langle g(x) + g'(x) \Delta x, h(x) + h'(x) \Delta x \rangle \\
&= \langle g(x),h(x) \rangle + \langle h(x), g'(x) \Delta x \rangle + \langle g(x), h'(x) \Delta x \rangle + \underbrace{\langle g'(x) \Delta x, h'(x) \Delta x \rangle}_{\text{negligible}} \\
&\approx \underbrace{\langle g(x), h(x) \rangle}_{F(x)} + \left(h(x)^T g'(x) + g(x)^T h'(x)\right)\Delta x.
\end{align}
Comparing this with the approximation
$$
F(x + \Delta x) \approx F(x) + F'(x) \Delta x
$$
reveals that
$$
\tag{1} F'(x) = h(x)^T g'(x) + g(x)^T h'(x).
$$
This is our product rule.

Now let's take $g(x) = x$ and $h(x) = Ax$, so that $F(x) = x^T A x$. Note that $g'(x) = I$ (the identity matrix) and $h'(x) = A$. Our product rule (1) tells us that
$$
F'(x) = (Ax)^T I + x^T A = x^T (A^T + A).
$$
The gradient of $F$ is
$$
\nabla F(x) = F'(x)^T = (A + A^T)x.
$$
If we assume that $A^T = A$, then $F'(x) = 2Ax$.

It follows that
$$
\nabla f(x) = 2Ax - 2b.
$$
So, setting $\nabla f(x)$ equal to $0$, we obtain
$$
2Ax - 2b = 0 \quad \text{or equivalently} \quad Ax = b.
$$

Answer (score 1):

For the gradient of $\frac{1}{2}x^TAx-b^Tx$, the latter part $-b^Tx$ is trivial to dealing with, and for the former part $\frac{1}{2}x^TAx$, as the differential of a product of two functions, it is not difficult to see that the result is
$$\frac{1}{2}[Ax+(x^TA)^T]=\frac{1}{2}(A+A^T)x.$$

So, is there an additional condition that $A^T=A$?
If so, we will derive what we want.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: There is a minimum reputation requirement to comment, so the above comment doesn't apply here.